# Need to get text value out of LinearLayout

Tags: testing, xamarin.android, automated-tests

Have the below piece of Android UI ouput got from Repl()

```
      [LinearLayout] id: "LayoutRoot"
                    [RelativeLayout > LinearLayout] id: "ClickableArea"
                      [LinearLayout]
                        [LinearLayout]
                          [TextView] id: "PrimaryText" text: "Cats"
                          [TextView] id: "SecondaryText" text: "1 animal"
                        [ImageView] id: "ErrorIcon"
                        [TextView] id: "ErrorCount" text: "1"
                      [FrameLayout] id: "SmallAccessory"
                        [ImageView] id: "Expand"
                    [View]
```

I am writing UI tests for an Android app, have 2 checks for the PrimaryText and SecondayText as well

```
Assert.IsNotEmpty(application.Query(q => q.Id("ClickableArea").Descendant().Text(UITestElements.HoldingPen.Liveweight)));
Assert.IsNotEmpty(application.Query(q => q.Id("ClickableArea").Descendant().Text(UITestElements.HoldingPen.Liveweight).Sibling().Id("SecondaryText").Text("1 animal")));
```

What I would like to be able to do is check the ErrorCount Text property for each ClickableArea, have tried variation of the above with Child, Sibling, Parent but just can't get my head around it.

Not all of them have an ErrorCount and the ID tags are not there if they do not have error

There are approx 30 of these ClickableAreas on the page and they do require scrolling to.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Hi, whehter the shared code works for `PrimaryText` and `SecondaryText`?

Comment: Yup the code for both works, if I change the text they will fail.

Comment: Okey, what do you mean "*if I change the text they will fail.*"?

Comment: If I change the text value it is looking for they will fail, so just proof that they work and find all the elements they are looking for, so I have the Sibling thing correct

Comment: Therefore, I can not understand the meaning of  "*check the ErrorCount Text property for each ClickableArea*". If the shared code works, you also can check the `ErrorCount` by using the same way.

Comment: It can't find it when I do it, have tried checkign it as a sibling, child, parent and it nevers finds it, thats the problem.

Comment: Because there is no more detailed document to explain more about Xamarin UITest, I have updated an answer with a workaround to achieve that. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to be able to do is check the ErrorCount Text property for each ClickableArea

I'm not sure whehter **Xmarin UITest** contains the way to search for the conrols between multiple **Layouts**, but you could use **AppResult** to query all the matched controls and check whether it's text is null.

For example, using the following way to get all the controls:

```
AppResult[] labelContainer = app.WaitForElement(x => x.Marked("ErrorCount");
//AppResult label = labelContainer[0];
```

Then you could use `for loop` to test each element of the given array of items.

```
for (int i = 0; i < labelContainer.Length ; i++)
{
    AppResult label = labelContainer[i];
    Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(label.Text)); 
}
```

Or one-line it like so :

```
Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(app.WaitForElement(x => x.Marked("ErrorCount")[0].Text));
```

Comment: How would I tie each error count to its PrimaryText?

eg ErrorCount of 2 could appear on 2 or more PrimaryText, but so could ErrorCount of 1.

Therefore I would need to index of the "ClickableArea" which belongsto PrimaryText of "Cats", then loop through the ErrorCount until I get to the index of "Cats" and check that value. 

That may work I will go and try

Thanks for pointing in that direction

Comment: If `LayoutRoot` contains multiple `ClickableArea`, and each `ClickableArea` contains only one unique control id. Then each item of `AppResult[]` represent each control of `ClickableArea`. And they will be arranged in order from top to bottom in Xaml. Then you will know which `ClickableArea` each control belongs to. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer,
look at all the parent level containers ( ("ClickableArea") ) and get the Descendants with the Id required ( .Descendant().Id("PrimaryText")) ) and then make a list ( .ToList() ) of them and find the index where the primary text = X

```
int indexnew = application.Query(q => q.Id("ClickableArea").Descendant().Id("PrimaryText")).ToList().FindIndex(q => q.Text.Contains("Cats"));
```

Comment: Hi, glad found the solution! Remember to mark the answer when you have time , it will help others who have similar issue.